# Cant run exe file after compiling in nasm

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, windows-10, nasm

I was trying to install nasm software on my win 10 x64 machine and run some simple code.

I compiled and linked it succesfully:

`nasm -f win32 hello.asm -o hello.obj`

`ld hello.obj -o hello.exe c:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll`

While trying to open exe file it doesnt run. There is message: `this app cannot run on your pc` and in console there is: `Permission denied`. 
Also, I don't have problem like that with working in other environments. Maybe it is something wrong with code, but i dont think so...

```
[bits 32]
extern _puts

section .data

hello:
db    "Hello world!", 0xa,0

section .text

_WinMain@16:

push hello
call _puts
add esp,4

xor eax, eax
ret
```

Comment: Show the commands used to assemble and more importantly, link. You did link, right? PS: that code is clearly 32 bit

Comment: ofc i linked it nasm -f win32 hello.asm -o hello.obj
ld hello.obj -o hello.exe c:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Run cmd.exe as Administrator should help.

Comment: It is never a good idea to just throw elevated privileges to a program that doesn't work as expected, and shouldn't need elevated privileges at the first place.

Comment: This answer is very vague and in theory could be used as advice for nearly any question on SO. If you want to help the original poster (from nearly three years ago, by the way) but you're not 100% sure of your answer, it's better to reply with a comment or question to the OP instead of an answer itself.